# How to add results of two select commands in same query and from same table - Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, sum

I have this query that works fine:

```
SELECT 
    RE.IDREUNIONFALLA as "IdReunion",
    NVL((select count(1) as pozos 
        from REUNION_FALLAPREMATURA 
        where IDREUNIONFALLA=RE.IDREUNIONFALLA  
        group by IDREUNIONFALLA),0)  as "PlanificadosFallas",
    NVL((select count(1) as pozos 
        from REUNION_FALLAPOZOS_AD 
        where IDREUNIONFALLA=RE.IDREUNIONFALLA  
        group by IDREUNIONFALLA),0)  as "PlanificadosPozos"
FROM  REUNIONFALLA RE
```

This query returns multiple rows with two columns, each of them with a int number, **like this:**

[image]

What i need to do, is to get the SUM from each row, in a new column. You can see what i mean on **the next image:**

[image]

I already thit this:

```
SELECT 
    NVL((SELECT count(1) as pozos 
        from REUNION_FALLAPREMATURA 
        where IDREUNIONFALLA=RE.IDREUNIONFALLA 
        group by IDREUNIONFALLA),0)  as "PlanificadosFallas",
    NVL((SELECT count(1) as pozos 
        from REUNION_FALLAPOZOS_AD 
        where IDREUNIONFALLA=RE.IDREUNIONFALLA 
        group by IDREUNIONFALLA),0)  as "PlanificadosPozos",
    NVL((SELECT  SUM(fallas) PlanificadosTotal 
        FROM -- i add this five lines
            ( 
                select count(1) as fallas 
                from REUNION_FALLAPREMATURA 
                where IDREUNIONFALLA=RE.IDREUNIONFALLA  
                group by IDREUNIONFALLA

                UNION ALL

                select count(1) as fallas 
                from REUNION_FALLAPOZOS_AD 
                where IDREUNIONFALLA=RE.IDREUNIONFALLA 
                group by IDREUNIONFALLA
            )),0) as "Total"
FROM  REUNIONFALLA RE
```

but i get this next error:

> **ORA-00904: "RE"."IDREUNIONFALLA": invalid identifier**

is there a solution for this?

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with PL/SQL, the name of a procedural programming language. It's all about Oracle SQL. I'll edit your tags and title accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[edit]
This one is cleaner :

```
SELECT 
    RE.IDREUNIONFALLA as "IdReunion",
    NVL(t1.pozos,0)  as "PlanificadosFallas",
    NVL(t2.pozos,0)  as "PlanificadosPozos",
    (NVL(t1.pozos,0)s + NVL(t2.pozos,0)) AS "Total"
FROM  REUNIONFALLA RE
LEFT JOIN (
    select IDREUNIONFALLA, count(1) as pozos
    from REUNION_FALLAPREMATURA 
    group by IDREUNIONFALLA
) t1 
    ON t1.IDREUNIONFALLA = RE.IDREUNIONFALLA
LEFT JOIN (
    select IDREUNIONFALLA, count(1) as pozos 
    from REUNION_FALLAPOZOS_AD 
    group by IDREUNIONFALLA
) t2 
    ON t2.IDREUNIONFALLA=RE.IDREUNIONFALLA
```

As you can see, you make the count a single time and not for each line : should run faster if you have a big number of line.

---

This should do it :

```
SELECT 
    t1.IdReunion,
    t1.PlanificadosFallas,
    t1.PlanificadosPozos,
    (t1.PlanificadosFallas + t1.PlanificadosPozos) AS "Total"
FROM (
    SELECT 
          RE.IDREUNIONFALLA as "IdReunion",
          NVL((select count(1) as pozos from REUNION_FALLAPREMATURA where IDREUNIONFALLA=RE.IDREUNIONFALLA  group by IDREUNIONFALLA),0)  as "PlanificadosFallas",
          NVL((select count(1) as pozos from REUNION_FALLAPOZOS_AD where IDREUNIONFALLA=RE.IDREUNIONFALLA  group by IDREUNIONFALLA),0)  as "PlanificadosPozos"
    FROM  REUNIONFALLA RE
) AS t1
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Im still having this next Error though: "ORA-00904: "T1"."IDREUNIONFALLA": invalid identifier".

Comment: @GabrielPeralta did you have `IDREUNIONFALLA` field in the `REUNION_FALLAPREMATURA` table ?

Comment: i add IDREUNIONFALLA to the LEFT JOIN sentence's and it worked! Thank's a lot!

Comment: @GabrielPeralta Ah yes, it's a sub query, I need to explicit it, you're right. You're welcome & don't forger to flag you question as solved with the "accept this answer" ;)